# How to put GPS system service in a local service so it can be killed to turn off GPS

Tags: android, gps

Like many others, I want to have an exit button that will turn off the GPS when the user leaves the app to conserve battery life.  Many discussions are posted basically saying this cannot be done but I have an application that does it so continue to try and find a way.  The developer of that application told me that he runs the internal GPS in a service that he wrote and that his exit key kills that service and vola, the GPS indicator goes off instantly.

My app is very time sensitive and I would like to use the equivalent of onLocationChanged that I use now when using the LocationListener part of the system service but have the system service inside a service I write so that I can kill it.

My question then is can I put the system GPS service inside a local service without adding any significant delay, without me having to poll the local service for updates.  Any help on how I can do this would be appreciates as this is my first Android app and although I have written tons of C and PHP code, this is new territory and a bit strange.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't want one app turning my GPS off for all my apps simply because I closed this one.  I would suggest sticking with using LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates() to request GPS updates (if enabled) and removeUpdates() when done.  If no apps are requesting updates then the power consumption is not a great concern.

Comment: The app that does turn off GPS only turns it off it his app is the only one using it.  If other apps are using GPS, it stays on.  This is just what I want to do and why I am asking my question.  Absent this and releasing the GPS in onPause allows the system to turn off GPS but it takes about an hour.

Comment: "If you back arrow out of the app, GPS stays on." Are you referring to your app, sounds like you are not finishing your GPS Service in this case. Perhaps you should execute the code associated with your `EXIT` Button in onDestroy() as well. Please post the relevant code, we should be able to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Like many others, I want to have an exit button that will turn off the GPS

You cannot "turn off the GPS". You can tell Android that *your app* no longer needs GPS (e.g., you no longer need GPS updates). *Android* will then determine whether or not to power down the GPS radio, depending on what else might be trying to use GPS at the moment.

> when the user leaves the app to conserve battery life.

You do not need a button for this. Simple apps, where only one activity needs GPS access, can simply request location updates in `onResume()` and remove them in `onPause()`. More complex apps might request location updates on the first `onResume()` that needs them, then remove those updates in `onUserLeaveHint()`, or do a reference-count of resume/pause operations to determine when to remove updates.

There may be scenarios where you really do want the user to have to explicitly say "stop using GPS" by clicking a button, but if you can avoid it, please do so.

> The developer of that application told me that he runs the internal GPS in a service that he wrote and that his exit key kills that service and vola, the GPS indicator goes off instantly.

Somehow the developer needs to determine when to start and stop this service. Rather than starting and stopping the service, they could request and remove the location updates, and have the same effect, while consuming less heap space and making it less likely that the user will attack you with task killers and the Force Stop button.

IMHO, the only reason to use a service with location updates is because you specifically want to consume location information in the background with no activities around.

Comment: I do a removeUpdates in the onPause of the page using GPS.  Eventually (about an hour later) the GPS will go off.  As I noted in the other comment, the app in question only turns off GPS if it was the only app using GPS.  If another app is using GPS it stays on but if this app is exited by hitting its EXIT button, the GPS goes off.  If you back arrow out of the app, GPS stays on.  This is what I want and it is kind of a pain that the developers have not allowed this to happen, but I know they are way smarter than I am...  I am only writing an app and only know what I want.

Comment: @AllenEdwards: "Eventually (about an hour later) the GPS will go off." -- and how have you determined this? If you are going by an icon in the status bar of an emulator, that is a flawed test.

Comment: I have previously used the GPS icon but since you brought it up I have done some tests seeing if the GPS is locked after certain amounts of time.  I find that corresponds to the GPS icon but the time is somethimes much shorter than I thought although it has definitely taken a toll on my battery to run these tests.  I guess it just isn't worth the trouble so I will just forget it as you suggest.